# All strings or characters change into numeric 1 in mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a simple registration system. I found a problem, however, all my data which inserted into database has changed into numeric.
It happens when I inserted those data via php, not command prompt or phpmyadmin. For example, I type first name, lastname, etc in the form, the value in my table is numeric 1. I don't know where this number came from. I browsing and browsing, and I don't know what is the keyword. Please see my code below and give suggestion or clear explanation.

```
//TABLE STRUCTURE
user_id INT (10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fname VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
access timestamp (15) NOT NULL,
primary key (user_id);

//DB CONNECTION
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbas = "user";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error("not connected"));
$data = mysql_select_db($dbas, $conn) or die(mysql_error("couldn't find"));

//FORM PROCCESS --> proccess.php
$id = isset($_POST['user_id']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['fname']));
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['lname']));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['username']));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['city']));
$access = date("m-d-y");

if(isset($_POST['submit']) !== '')
{
    if($id == '' && $fname == '' && $lname == '' && $username == '' && $city == '' && $access == ''){
        echo "please fill empty";
    } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (user_id, fname, lname, username, city, access) VALUES (null, '".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$username."', '".$city."', '".$access."')");

        if($sql)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
}

//RETRIEVE DATA
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($getit = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$getit['fname']. "<td/>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}

// FORM STRUCTURE
<form action="proccess.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="access">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: It means the code that I used is no longer valid? so, where the number 1 came from?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. It means the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you shouldn't use it any more. This is unrelated to actual issue. `1` is what the `isset()` returns. It is same as `TRUE`. Similarly `0` means `FALSE`.

Answer (score 5):

You have the following in your code:

```
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['fname']));
```

**`isset()` returns a boolean true or false, not the actual value itself.** So essentially, you'll just be doing:

```
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string(1);
```

From the [documentation for `isset()`](http://php.net/isset#refsect1-function.isset-returnvalues):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns **TRUE** if var exists and has value other than NULL, **FALSE**
>   otherwise.

Comment: Yeah if you want to check if those POST variables are set before assigning them you should do this: if(isset($_POST['fname'])) { $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']); }

Comment: Hi, I leave `isset()` and try using ternary operator, and success. Thanks for everyone. Good luck for you all

Answer (score 0):

```
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['city']));
```

Breaking it down -

Escape the string to make it safe(r)

Do we have the post for city

This returns 1 for yes and 0 for no.

but you are not actually getting the value.

```
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['fname']) == 1 ? $_POST['fname'] : ""));
```

This will check if it is set - if it is set $city to the post value, otherwise enter a blank value (? works like an if statement : is like an else)

Accept Abhik Chakraborty answer - dont want to snipe him just wanted to show you how to fix it!

Comment: Hi, @Graham, thanks for your suggestion. I use ternary operator, but without `==1` and my problem solved

Comment: Yes - I always go basic(ish) - exactly correct without the ==1 that was just to show the logic! Glad it helped - good luck!